# ComboBox SelectedItem binding writes NULL to source property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a UserControl that has a ComboBox with binding to one of its own dependency Properties.

```
<UserControl x:Class="XamlParserComboBoxTest.ItemEditor" x:Name="aEditor">
    <Grid>
      <ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Colors}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=aEditor, 
                                       Path=Item.Color, 
                                       Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This DependencyProperty is filled with an instance of the `Item` Type:

```
public class Item : ViewModelBase
{
    private Color _color { get; set; }
    public Color Color
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set
        {
            _color = value;
            if (value == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Color set to NULL");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            OnPropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }
}

public class Color
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When the UserControl is replaced with another UserControl, the Item's `Color` setter is called with `NULL` value. Properties bound to other controls don't experience any change.

While I have worked my way around this, I really need to understand what causes this and what's the best way to solve it.

**EDIT:** According to the stack trace, the null value comes from `Item's` base class, but I don't see how. Full source code available [here](http://edelmeier.com/xamlparsercomboboxtest.zip). To reproduce the issue, start it up and press the "Show Item" button twice.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"When the UserControl is replaced with another UserControl"`? and where is the `ItemsSource` coming from?

Comment: @HighCore, please check the source code. I only show one editor control in my window's center by binding a `ContentControl`'s content to a property that's set by my ICommand implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this using the `TargetNullValue` and possibly `FallbackValue` properties:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Colors}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=aEditor, Path=Item.Color, 
    TargetNullValue=Black, FallbackValue=Black, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: As far as I know this only affects the ComboBox item side of the binding while he has the problem at the other side ...

Answer (score 0):

You can put a breakpoint where you have the message box and check the call stack. Then you will know who's setting the null.

Then probably you will be able to use a tool like 'JustDecompile' to find out why. If you are not used to that just post here the  call stack and I'll do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, SoMoS. Could you explain how JustDecompile can help me? Given that name, I thought it was a decompiler...

Comment: When you have the stack trace available then you will be able to know why the null is being set and then you know how to avoid it.

Comment: I have uploaded the source code. Meanwhile I'd like to learn what you proposed, but don't know how to feed JustDecompile a stacktrace...

Comment: Just do what I wrote on the answer. Put a breakpoint on the message box and go to visual studio -> debug -> windows -> callstack and tell me what's there. You won't feed the callstack to the decompiler, instead you will looks at what is .Net doing to put a null there.